# Javascript Files not Enqueuing properly in Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm converting a *TextPattern* site to a *Wordpress* theme. The site is just getting started, up at http://ronvilwordpress.krd-design.net .   I am having an issue enqueing the *JavaScript* files.  I dropped the following code into my *functions.php* file:

---

```
<?php

// load javascript
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_files' );

function load_js_files() {
wp_register_script( 'modernizr', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .     '/javascript/modernizr-1.7.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
wp_register_script( 'plugins', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/javascript/plugins.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
wp_register_script( 'dd_belatedpng', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/javascript/dd_belatedpng.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
wp_register_script( 'script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/javascript/script.js',  array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
wp_register_script( 'xregex', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/javascript/xregex.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script('modernizr');
wp_enqueue_script('dd_belatedpng');
wp_enqueue_script('plugins');
wp_enqueue_script('script');
wp_enqueue_script('xregex');
}



?>
```

---

The *JavaScript* files are located in a folder labelled **'javascript'** in the root of the theme folder, so I don't think it's an issue with the files paths.

Anyone else run into this problem?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You never stated the exact problem.  What is it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the file paths, Wordpress is enqueuing the files with the correct paths, the JS is accessible.  It is inserting them into the  rather than the  though.  Not that that is your issue, you have a JS error in dd_belatedpng.js, get rid of that for the moment and then see where you are with the other files.